# GeometryCollection styling in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, sld, geometrycollection

I am trying to style an GeometryCollection geometry data type from PotGIS table in Geoserver. I have not found any examples on the Internet how to do it nor is it supported in Geoserver or not. When I try to style it using standard PolygonSymbolizer, LineSymbolizer and PointSymbolizer I get strange behaviours. For example, filled non-closed linestrings, non-exitsting points appear on linestring etc. This is one example of my SLD file and rendered WMS request.

Am I doing something wrong in my SLD?

Is GeometryCollection supported in Geoserver?

Example of SLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
       <Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:Function name="geometryType">
               <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>GeometryCollection</ogc:Literal>
         </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">6</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#00FF00</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">round</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
         <PointSymbolizer>
              <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                  <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                  <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#0000FF</CssParameter>
                  </Fill>
                </Mark>
              <Size>9</Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Rendered WMS request with provided SLD file:

[image: Rendered WMS request with provided SLD file]

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the correct behaviour as described by the [SLD Spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld). If you want to only apply one symbolizer to a feature then you need to provide a filter that selects one (or more) of the symbolizers for each feature.

The GeoServer documentation covers how to handle multiple geometries in one column quite clearly [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html).

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I have geometrycollection which has points, lines and poligons, how can I select particular type from that geometrycollection object?

Comment: I might go to making views into PostGIS or SQL View layer in GeoServer for splitting GeometryCollections to point/multipoint, linestring/multilinestring, and polygon/multipolygon layers. Then the layers could be styled in a reasonable way and combined back together by making a WMS layer group. Very few software can style geometrycollections well. OpenJUMP is one that can but it does not help you with your web service.

Comment: easiest way is the filter on geometry type

Comment: @user30184 I am aware of this approach, but I wanted to avoid it :) .. thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @iant if I filler by geometry type, I get geometry type geometrycollection ... what to with it then? With filtering by geometry type I do not get point, linestring and polygon.

Comment: You are right, you can't filter by geometry type directly. You have now only features of one type - geometrycollections. You must explode the collections first before you have elementary geometries to filter. Have you thought about reading data with WFS and to apply styles on the client side?

Comment: I believe you will have to write a new filter function that extracts sub-geometries of a given type and plug it in. There is a tutorial here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html